# Confusing CSS class/styles order

Tags: css, sass, styles

Can anyone please explain to me why my CSS classname order is not being respected? Even though .x14/.x15 are styles in the HTML directly, they are still classnames?

[image]
[image]

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

CSS Works based on specificity and order of declarations, in your case .x14 and .x15 appears to be inline styles and this have priority of class elements on a style archive so **Inline style > file style**

Here follow a list of specificity and his order from lowest priority to highest priority

**Universal Selectors**

```
*{
   background: red;
 }
```

*This attribute to all elements on page will have now a background red*

**Class Selector**

```
.foo{
  background: green;
}
```

*This will set for the element with the **foo** class a green background*

**Selector Attributes**

```
a[target="_blank"]{
  color: blue;
}
```

*This will match only **a** elements with **target="_blank"***

**Pseudo-classes**

```
div:hover{
  background: yellow;
}
```

*This will set a yellow background in every div when **mouse over** this*

**ID Selectors**

```
#foo{
  background: pink;
}
```

*This will set a background pink for only one element who have the id **foo** setted (id is unique)*

**Inline Style**

```
<style>
  .foo{
    background: purple;
  }
</style>
```

*As an inline style, it will override the .foo class setted on css file, and change the green background to **purple** background*

---

And css have another two other specificity should be overrided

**Important Property**

```
.foo{
   background: gray !important;
}
```

*This will override all background style setted previous on .foo class*

**Not pseudo-element**

```
h1:not(.foo){
  font-size: 1rem;
}
```

*this will set for all h1 minus those that have class **foo***

---

Hope it helps you and many other devs with questions on css specificity.

Comment: So I knew about css priority. If they are inline styles though, why do they show under classnames? ie. .x14 has an associated style. I think the <style> tag just tells us that the styles for those classes are in the head of the HTML document. They are not inline-styles. Regardless of the source of the css, shouldn't the classnames have priority based on position in the classname?

Comment: Well according what you mentioned on your question _"Even though .x14/.x15 are styles in the HTML directly"_ both of this class has priority about the **login-form_field** because it is a inline-style